# django can i use prefetch_related on a evaluated queryset without redoing the initial query

Tags: django, performance, orm, django-queryset

consider this code

```
users = UserProfile.objects.all()[:10]
# evaluate the query set
users_list = list(users)

users = users.prefetch_related('posts')
```

i want to know that using prefetch_related on queryset after it is evaluated will repeat the query on UserProfile model or not.
Thanks.

Comment: it will not repeat the query... until you cause the new queryset to be evaluated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: How to prefetch related for a model instance. Perhaps by wrapping in a queryset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759975/django-how-to-prefetch-related-for-a-model-instance-perhaps-by-wrapping-in-a-q)

Answer (score 1):

No. Until you evaluate it again, as it cannot magically pull the extra data from the database.

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> from app.models import Foo
>>> bar = Foo.objects.all()[:1]
>>> len(connection.queries)
0
>>> bar_list = list(bar)
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
>>> bar = bar.prefetch_related('thing')
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
>>> bar_list = list(bar)
>>> len(connection.queries)
2
```

Comment: The last number should be a 3. It is executing both the base query and the prefetch query. Tested with django 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

No, in this scenario, the query will hit only when you call the variable users.

```
print users
```

Hit:

```
(0.000) QUERY = 'SELECT “userprofile"."id" INNER JOIN “posts" ON ( “userprofile"."usuari...
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated), the QuerySet API executes the database query at the first time you iterate over it. In your case the iteration happens because of the `list(users)`.

The `prefetch_related` function would have an effect on the first query if you would call it before execution.

So, that means: Yes, you can call `prefetch_related` after iteration, but the `QuerySet` has to do a new database query to get the missing information about the posts. [QuerySets are cloned every time](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L861) you call a function like `prefetch_related`. So, the next iteration is the first one for the cloned object.