# Django: How to prefetch related for a model instance. Perhaps by wrapping in a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, query-optimization

I use Django rest framework and I have decent nesting in my model relations.

I'm working on optimizing my queries. Many of my functions consume or manipulate a single instance of model and it's often further downstream in the data flow that it turns out I need some prefetching. One classic instance of this is with DRF serializers. Here's an example.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def fetch_user_profile(request):
    profile = request.user.profile # has many nested relationships

    return Response(UserProfileSerializer(profile).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) # this ends up taking many queries
```

I've seen some solutions suggesting passing queryset with `prefetch_related` in the context although I haven't been able to get a full picture on how that would work (I've only found a couple of places that discuss it partially, might open a whole other question on that).

**An easy fix (and one that would generalize beyond serializers) would be if I can have a wrapper function to wrap my instance in a queryset and then call prefetch on that, passing it into the serializer.**

Something like:

```
def queryset_wrap(instance):
    return type(instance).objects.filter(id=instance.id)
```

**I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.**

Answer (score 5):

I haven't yet used this myself, but I believe that it is the `prefetch_related_objects()` function that you are looking for, introduced in Django 1.10

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related-objects):

> Prefetches the given lookups on an iterable of model instances. This is useful in code that receives a list of model instances as opposed to a QuerySet; for example, when fetching models from a cache or instantiating them manually.
>
> Pass an iterable of model instances (must all be of the same class) and the lookups or Prefetch objects you want to prefetch for. For example:

```
>>> from django.db.models import prefetch_related_objects
>>> restaurants = fetch_top_restaurants_from_cache()  # A list of Restaurants
>>> prefetch_related_objects(restaurants, 'pizzas__toppings')
```

Since it takes an iterable, you can wrap your instance in a list:

```
prefetch_related_objects([profile], "relevant_attribute_1", "relevant_attribute_2")
```